# Calculated Weighted Average in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, weighted-average

I am trying to calculate the YTD value for every month. How could I achieve this in SQL Server?

[image]

Green is how my data looks in the table.I am suppose to calculate the one in Yellow. Your help will be much appreciated.

```
Year    Month   Monthly_Score   N_size  YTD_Score
2017    1        70             10       70*10/10
2017    2        80             20       70*10/(10+20) + 80 *20 /(10+20)
2017    3        90             30       70*10/(10+20+30) + 80 * 20 /(10+20+30) 
                                         +90*30/(10+20+30)
```

Comment: which version of sql server are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the window function `SUM` if your version of SQL Server supports it.

```
select year,month,monthly_score,n_size,
1.0*sum(monthly_score*n_size) over(partition by year order by month)/
sum(n_size) over(partition by year order by month)
from yourtable
```

Note that the value resets every year.

Edit: For SQL Server versions below 2012 that support `outer apply`.

```
select y.year,y.month,y.monthly_score,y.n_size,t.ytd_score
from yourtable y
outer apply (select 1.0*sum(monthly_score*n_size)/sum(n_size) as ytd_score 
             from yourtable y1 
             where y.year=y1.year and y1.month<=y.month
            ) t
```

Comment: That's awesome! I think it should work. I just tried. I am going to test for others and let you know.

Comment: Thank you so much! I have been trying this since couple of hours now. Appreciate it.

Comment: If this has to do in SQL Server 2008, how can this be done? please help!

Comment: I tried implementing your query using my tables, but the results are not the same .(Compared with excel). Anything you think that I am missing?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the window variant of `sum` to sum to calculate running totals:

```
SELECT [Year], [Month], [Monthly_Score], [N_Size],
       SUM([Monthly_Score] * [N_Size]) 
          OVER (ORDER BY [Year], [Month]
          ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) / 
      SUM([N_Size]) 
          OVER (ORDER BY [Year], [Month]
          ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS YTD_Score
FROM  my_table
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your time.  I just tried something similar but without UNBOUNDED PRECEDING and CURRENT ROW and it worked. Just curious what difference does this make?

Comment: If this has to be done in SQL Server 2008. How can this be achieved?